# Replacing keyboard with voice control

Tags: keyboard, voice-recognition

I am sick of using a keyboard.

Has anyone had any success with voice control of their computer, using tools such as Dragon Naturally Speaking? What about coding tasks, and control of an IDE? Any problems specific to that?

Comment: Sick of using a keyboard? I totally can't imagine using a computer via voice control - I can't imagine having the same degree of control I have with a keyboard with only my voice.

Comment: cat walks by ... "Stop that!" computer kills 3-day running process.

Comment: @Dominic: A keyboard isn't an option for some disabled people, people suffering from tendonitis/carpal tunnel syndrome, car applications, wearable computing,  ...  There are many situations like this.

I use Linux, and unfortunately there are no more good voice command apps for Linux, so I can't help you.  Sorry.

Comment: Writing code may not be a very suitable task for some of those environments. (no disrespect to people with physical problems intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current state of Voice Recognition, it is not advisable to even think of ***replacing*** your keyboard with it.

I have done some basic experiments with Vista's voice recognition engine, however I haven't found it to be suited for any voice-to-text task. This is not even speaking of IDE integration, which would require mapping language keywords (what to do about brackets?) to voice commands.

On the other hand, it might be very well possible to ***supplement*** your input possibilities with voice recognition for commands. But I don't think voice commands will inherently ever come close to the speed hitting an intelligent shortcut on my keyboard.

I have always tried to get my fingers on a NIA (Neural Impulse Actuator) such as OCZ is [offering](http://www.ocztechnology.com/products/ocz_peripherals/nia-neural_impulse_actuator). This might solve the speed issue, and is in theory even faster than a keyboard shortcut. However, you won't have many possible commands and I heard it requires significant training and concentration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use voice control to replace a keyboard. The mouse can be moved and clicked by voice also. Voice control from Dragon executes as quick as bindkey presses. Training is 1/2hr. I use it through VNC to sends commands to linux tools.
Research dragonfly2 from there you can find many resources.